# How to use Javascript if statement when linked with bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I've hit a wall with trying to get my JavaScript if statement to work when using bootstraps drop down menu.

Goal: There are 2 drop down menu's. The user will select one value from each, based on what the user selects something will happen. I've seen many examples using the  method however bootstrap seems to be a bit different. Also, I've seen a lot of people recommend jQuery because it's easier but I prefer to use Javascript (I'm learning). If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, or if my approach is totally off base please kindly let me know the right approach. Also, I currently don't have the "id" in my html because I'm not sure where to put it. Cheers.

```
HTML: 

    <!--Drop down Item 1 -->
<h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
    Eye Color
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="brown"> Brown</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="blue"> Blue</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="green"> Green</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="hazel"> Hazel</a>
  </div>

</div>


<!--Drop down Item 2-->
<h4 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> What is your skin tone</h4>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
    Skin Tone
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" onchange="dropdownChange();">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/fair.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="fair"> Fair (porcelain)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/light.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="light"> Light (fair to light)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/medium.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="medium"> Medium (light to medium)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/bronze_dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="bronze"> Bronze dark (deep tan)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/tan.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="tan"> Tan (warm to medium)</a>   
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" value="rich"> Rich (deep)</a>
  </div>

</div>

<br>

<!--Result-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg active" style="background-color: #3e4444;"> Submit</button>

JS: 

    function validate()   {
var a =document.getElementById("eye_color").value;
var b =document.getElementById("skin_tone").value;
if (a == "green" && b == "fair"){
alert("Brown is your best hair color!!");
}    
}
```

Comment: ```The user will select one value from each, based on what the user selects something will happen. I've seen many examples using the method however bootstrap seems to be a bit different.``` What exactly do you want to happen? Could you share an example?

Comment: Sure thing. I'm trying to make a "Best hair color app," based off what the user selects. Drop down 1: select eye color, Drop down 2: select skin tone. Once user selects one value from each drop down and clicks submit, the generator will spit out what their best hair color would be(for now I'm just using an alert). I've added a photo for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure Javascript (no jQuery) example of what I *think* you have asked for.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

      document.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
              initApplication();
          }
      }

      var eyeColor = null;
      function selectMenu1(value){
        eyeColor = value;
      }

      var skinTone = null;
      function selectMenu2(value){
        skinTone = value;
      }

      function validate()   {
        if (eyeColor && skinTone){
          alert(`You selected ${eyeColor} eye colour and ${skinTone} skin tone.`);
          //////////////////////////
          //////////////////////////
          //put your extra conditions below
          //////////////////////////
          //////////////////////////
          if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="fair"){
            alert("You should have w/e colour hair...");
          } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="tan"){
            alert("You should have w/e colour hair...");
          }
        }
        else if (!eyeColor){
          alert("Please pick an eye colour");
        }
        else if (!skinTone){
          alert("Please pick a skin tone");
        }
      }

      function initApplication(){
        //setup dropdown menu selection events
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu")).forEach((menu,idx)=>{
          if (!menu.attributes.onchange) return;
          const menuCallbackName = menu.attributes.onchange.value;
          const fetchedCallback = window[menuCallbackName] || null;

          if (fetchedCallback){
            Array.from(menu.children).forEach((child)=>{
              const callbackValue = child.attributes.data ? child.attributes.data.value : null;
              if (callbackValue) child.onclick = () => fetchedCallback(callbackValue);
            });
          } else console.error(`No callback function named ${menuCallbackName} for menu ${idx}`);

        });
      }



    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Drop down Item 1 -->
    <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
        Eye Color
      </button>


      <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="brown"><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle"> Brown</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="blue"><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Blue</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="green"><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Green</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="hazel"><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Hazel</a>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!--Drop down Item 2-->
    <h4 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> What is your skin tone</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
        Skin Tone
      </button>

      <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="fair"><img src="img/fair.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Fair (porcelain)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="light"><img src="img/light.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Light (fair to light)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="medium"><img src="img/medium.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Medium (light to medium)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="bronze"><img src="img/bronze_dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Bronze dark (deep tan)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="tan"><img src="img/tan.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Tan (warm to medium)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="rich"><img src="img/dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Rich (deep)</a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Result-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg active" style="background-color: #3e4444;" onclick="validate()"> Submit</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, Jonathan. Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to start with. Thank you! I will be adding lot of extra conditions based off what the user selects. It seems I was way off base. I can see why others would recommend jQuery. Would you say this is intermediate JS? I noticed the id = menu1 was not added to the html, should I incorporate that? Also, I ran the snippet here and it works however on my local host, I couldn't get the code to work when I hit submit?

Comment: I got the Submit button to wk, nevermind! Thanks so much!

Comment: No need for any ids